# Is it possible to prevent wrapping of child elements in HTML?

Tags: html, css-float, word-wrap

```
.container
{
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0px;
 height: 25px;
 left: 200px;
 padding-right: 5px;
 background-color: black;
 overflow: hidden;
}


.child
{
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 height: 100%;
 width: 95px;
 background-color: #99CCFF;
 margin-left: 5px;
}
```

I when the size of the browser window is smaller than will allow for all the children to fit without wrapping I would like there to be a scrollbar, not the default mechanism of the child elements wrapping.

I'm not in control of the number of child elements so I can not set a width on the container. How can I prevent the wrapping of the child elements?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you don't want wrapping, you should not use floats - they were created specifically for wrapping.

Use a parent container with `overflow:auto` and `white-space:nowrap` and children with `display:inline` or `inline-block`.

Comment: inline-block was what I needed to use. Thanks

Comment: @Justin808: the downside is that if you want it to work on older browsers (FF2, IE6-7), you will need [a bunch of workarounds](http://foohack.com/2007/11/cross-browser-support-for-inline-block-styling/)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a parent holder () of all childes. And then use the overflow:auto of that div. If that doesn't work then also use self.innerHeight and self.innerWidth (via javascript) for the div height and width.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really possible with simple HTML and CSS. Without knowing the number of child elements, the only way would be to dynamically set a min-width using JavaScript, based on the number of child elements and their total width.